# Compare two datasets from different databases using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, dataset

For data assurance, my task is two compare two datasets from different databases. Currently I am performing the cell-by-cell value comparison which is a Brute Force method and is consuming lot of time.

I would like to know if there are any methods which would save my time and memory space, which is able to provide a result indication "***Tables are identical***" or "***Tables are not identical***".

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If they are from different sources, there is no other way than comparing them cell by cell AFAIK. However I can suggest you something that will probably increasing comparison speed by many folds. If your DataTables have identical structures, which they hopefully should since you're already comparing them cell by cell, try comparing `ItemArray` of each pair of rows instead of accessing them by column index or column names (or row properties if you're using strongly-typed DataSets). This will hopefully give you much better results.

If you're using .NET 3.5 or above, this line should do it:

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(row1.ItemArray, row2.ItemArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought . I will give it a try and check the difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a checksum for each table and compare the them?

Something like:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*)) FROM TableX
```

This might need a ORDER BY to be more precise.

Comment: My impression is that he needs to compare DataSets, not SQL Server tables, as evident from the tags.

Comment: Yeah, that could be true. But if the task is to compare the content of two tables (as far as I understand it), why load the whole data from the servers if you can just load two checksums and compare them in code?

Comment: Correct. Let's see if he provides more explanation.

Comment: One problem with this approch is that it might return false equalities. Two equals checksums doesn't ensure tables are equals in content. On the other hand it doesn't return false inequalities.

Comment: @JesúsLópez How do you mean that they are not equal in content?

Comment: They might be not equal in content. Two different contents might have the same checksum, this is known as hash collisions ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science) ). It is because the number of different contents is much bigger than the number of different checksums

Comment: While this is true, the chances are slim. The question is, if the performance benefit is worth the risk, in my experience it often is.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all your replies.

I would make my problem statement clear, as my question appears to be vague.

Consider an instance where we have migrated all database objects(User Defined Tables..) from SQL Server database to Oracle database. To check whether the migrated data is the same as source, what would be the best (better performance) method that I can follow.

Currently, with Dataset, it takes really lot of time for cell-by-cell comparison, which is not efficient. And there can be memory issues if the data being pulled from the tables are very big in size.

Kindly help me.

Comment: @JamesBlond - As Lopez mentioned above, won't I face any issues when using CHECKSUM_AGG function, since the system functions might not give similar results on different database engines. So anything that can be done via the code, will be really helpful.

For ex, CHECKSUM_AGG equivalent for SAP HANA is unavailable.